# Advance Programming in the Unix Environment: Get Configuration Limits Figure 2.12 "Build C Program to print all supported configuration limits"

Tags: c, linux, unix, awk, redhat

The author claims that his awk script will print out all the limits for a POSIX.1 and XSI compliant system. I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago). When I run his awk script it does not seem to be printing out the `#ifdef` portion of the C program. My thoughts are that sysconf.sym do not exist on this distribution, therefore the while loops never run. Could someone please confirm that? If this is the case what changes would I need to make to the awk script to get it to print out the `#ifdef` portion of the code? The awk script is:

```
# Run with awk -f <awk_script>

BEGIN   {
    printf("#include \"apue.h\"\n")
    printf("#include <errno.h>\n")
    printf("#include <limits.h>\n")
    printf("#include <stdio.h>\n")
    printf("\n")

    printf("int log_to_stderr = 0;\n")

    printf("static void pr_sysconf(char *, int);\n")
    printf("static void pr_pathconf(char *, char *, int);\n")
    printf("\n")
    printf("int\n")
    printf("main(int argc, char *argv[])\n")
    printf("{\n")
    printf(" if (argc != 2)\n")
    printf("  err_quit(\"usage: a.out <dirname>\");\n\n")
    FS="\t+"
    while (getline <"sysconf.sym" > 0) {
        printf("#ifdef %s\n", $1)
        printf(" printf(\"%s defined to be %%d\\n\", %s+0);\n", $1, $1)
        printf("#else\n")
        printf(" printf(\"no symbol for %s\\n\");\n", $1)
        printf("#endif\n")
        printf("#ifdef %s\n", $2)
        printf(" pr_sysconf(\"%s =\", %s);\n", $1, $2)
        printf("#else\n")
        printf(" printf(\"no symbol for %s\\n\");\n", $2)
        printf("#endif\n")
    }
    close("sysconf.sym")
    while (getline <"pathconf.sym" > 0) {
        printf("#ifdef %s\n", $1)
        printf(" printf(\"%s defined to be %%d\\n\", %s+0);\n", $1, $1)
        printf("#else\n")
        printf(" printf(\"no symbol for %s\\n\");\n", $1)
        printf("#endif\n")
        printf("#ifdef %s\n", $2)
        printf(" pr_pathconf(\"%s =\", argv[1], %s);\n", $1, $2)
        printf("#else\n")
        printf(" printf(\"no symbol for %s\\n\");\n", $2)
        printf("#endif\n")
    }
    close("pathconf.sym")
    exit
}
END {
    printf(" exit(0);\n")
    printf("}\n\n")
    printf("static void\n")
    printf("pr_sysconf(char *mesg, int name)\n")
    printf("{\n")
    printf(" long val;\n\n")
    printf(" fputs(mesg, stdout);\n")
    printf(" errno = 0;\n")
    printf(" if ((val = sysconf(name)) < 0) {\n")
    printf("  if (errno != 0) {\n")
    printf("   if (errno == EINVAL)\n")
    printf("    fputs(\" (not supported)\\n\", stdout);\n")
    printf("   else\n")
    printf("    err_sys(\"sysconf error\");\n")
    printf("  } else {\n")
    printf("   fputs(\" (no limit)\\n\", stdout);\n")
    printf("  }\n")
    printf(" } else {\n")
    printf("  printf(\" %%ld\\n\", val);\n")
    printf(" }\n")
    printf("}\n\n")
    printf("static void\n")
    printf("pr_pathconf(char *mesg, char *path, int name)\n")
    printf("{\n")
    printf(" long val;\n")
    printf("\n")
    printf(" fputs(mesg, stdout);\n")
    printf(" errno = 0;\n")
    printf(" if ((val = pathconf(path, name)) < 0) {\n")
    printf("  if (errno != 0) {\n")
    printf("   if (errno == EINVAL)\n")
    printf("    fputs(\" (not supported)\\n\", stdout);\n")
    printf("   else\n")
    printf("    err_sys(\"pathconf error, path = %%s\", path);\n")
    printf("  } else {\n")
    printf("   fputs(\" (no limit)\\n\", stdout);\n")
    printf("  }\n")
    printf(" } else {\n")
    printf("  printf(\" %%ld\\n\", val);\n")
    printf(" }\n")
    printf("}\n")
}
```

---

**Update**

If you would like the apue.h header so you can compile the C program that can be found at.
[apue.h](http://matthewh.me/scripts/browser/c/unix_system_programming/src/include/apue.h)

Comment: What limits are these? The same as shown by `ulimit -a`?

Comment: ulimit command contains some of them, however according to the book, inorder for the system to be POSIX.1 compliant there are several others. Example being ARG_MAX -- maximum lenght in bytes of arugments to the exec functions.

Comment: there is no path for the `sysconf.sym`. Unless you just happen to be running this script in the dir with sysconf.sym, then it won't work. use unix `find / -name sysconf.sym` to see if it is available on your system. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry I should of specified that I have already run the find command for that file, and it did not turn up. The author does not even hint at where it would be on a Unix system. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that *sysconf.sym* and *pathconf.sym* had to be written or were supplied on disk or something.  It's been a while since I read APUE.

*Update:* google turned up the following link http://www.cs.karelia.ru/~vadim/sp2009/apue.2e/std/

Comment: Thanks, your link has everything one needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the files from here: http://www.apuebook.com/sourcecode.html

Answer (score 1):

I think Rago mentions getconf in the 2nd Edtion of APUE.  Aside from losing the fun of debugging the awk,  code it is meant to serve the purpose you require, and do it portably.

Check out:

```
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/getconf.html
```